# What's the easiest way to recursively build the same target in all subdirectories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project with several components and subcomponents.  I'd like a `make` command in the top directory to go to the subdirectories and run a child `make` for the given target.  I know I can write lots of individual `sh` commands each consisting of a `cd` followed by a `make` invocation but I sense there must be an easier or even more automatic way.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is to use make's natural ability to run lots of commands, and not use shell looping at all.

If you don't want to list the subdirectories directly in your makefile (I personally always list them by hand: it's safer and it's not too big a deal since new directories don't happen all the time), then to find all immediate subdirectories with makefiles you can:

```
SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %/Makefile,%,$(wildcard */Makefile))
```

Now figure out what target the user asked for.  If they didn't ask for one we'll use `all` as the default target (you can change this if you like of course):

```
GOALS := $(or $(MAKECMDGOALS),all)
```

Then create target(s) that depend on all subdirs and for each subdirectory, run the same targets we were given on the command line:

```
.PHONY: $(GOALS) $(SUBDIRS)
$(GOALS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Note, this will clearly only work with GNU make.

Comment: I like your wildcard better than mine and will steal after testing.  I don't see a need to spawn child makes in parallel because any given make will already be trying to use multiple jobs, no?  For instance if I want ten jobs in parallel, and give -j10, I don't want to simulatenously spawn FOUR CHILDREN all also trying to do -j10.  Just passing control to another -j10 make, waiting for it to finish, then running another should be OK?  I mean I myself am running up to 9 other jobs, so even what I write is too much, unless you see a solution?

Comment: GNU make provides a "jobserver" facility where all recursively invoked make instances share a single set of job tokens.  So, regardless of how many recursive invocations of make you use if you run `-j10` you will never have more than 10 jobs across all those instances running at the same time.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Job-Slots.html

Comment: Sorry I had a typo.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will find ALL subdirectories that contain a file called `Makefile` and run a `make` with the same target there.

`SubMakefiles` is simply a file find, and will return something like `./Makefile foo/Makefile bar/Makefile`.  From that, the `dir` command leaves us with `./ foo/ bar/`, and the `filter-out` removes the `./`.  That gives us a list we can easily iterate over with the `sh` processor that interprets `make` commands.  As a final detail, if it returns an error error we ourselves return that same error with `|| exit $$?`.

Note this will not work properly with either the `-k` or `-j` make options because all the sub-makes are invoked from a single recipe.

```
# Make the same target in all subdirectories with a Makefile.
SubMakefiles    = $(shell find -L . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Makefile)
SubMakeDirs     = $(filter-out ./,$(dir $(SubMakefiles)))

clean depend all::
        @for dir in $(SubMakeDirs); do \
            $(MAKE) -C $$dir $@ || exit $$?; \
        done
```

Comment: There are a few issues here: first, you should never use `make` when invoking sub-makes.  You should always use the variable `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}` if you prefer).  Second, you don't need to run the sub-make in a sub-shell (you don't need the `(`..`)` parens).  Third, this will not work properly with either the `-k` or `-j` make options because all the sub-makes are invoked from a single recipe.